# Django Rest Framework: @Action Route with same url_path as Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to POST to a DRF Viewset Detail Route. Is this possible? I know with DRF you can override the Create field, but this won't allow you to access the detail route.

Specifically in this example I want the design of the route to be `POST /foo/<pk>/`, and not some route like `POST /foo/<pk>/bar/`.

Here's what I want to accomplish, notice the `IS_THERE_A_WAY_TO_DO_THIS`:

```
class FooViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    """
    Foo-related viewsets.
    """

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = models.Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.FooSerializer

    @action(
        methods=["post"],
        detail=True,
        permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated],
        url_path="", <-- IS_THERE_A_WAY_TO_DO_THIS? Normally this wont work.
        url_name="foobar",
    )
    def foobar_process(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
...
router.register(r"foo", FooViewSet, basename="foo")
...

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r"^", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: can you show how did you register your view in URLs?

Comment: Sure, it's just the standard Viewset router.

Comment: have you tried to put anything for **`url_path`** ?

Comment: if you'd put **`url_path='bar'`**, DRF will generate an endpoint as `/foo/<FOO_Object_PK>/bar/`. Ex: **`/foo/123/bar/`

Comment: Yes, I want it to be nothing, not /bar/.

Comment: means, `/foo/123/` or `/foo/` ?

Comment: meaning  /foo/123/